# Is it possible to get the value that will be returned from a function if it's not stored in a variable?

Tags: ruby

I'm debugging a method that looks like this

```rb
def method
  if something
   "a"
  elsif somethingelse
   "b"
  #elseif ...
  else
   "z"
  end
  # the current return value is ???
end
```

The way ruby works gives the impression that every expression returns a value **and** it is saved somewhere. And the last one is going to be returned at the end of the method (if no `return` is found).

In the case above, the if condition returns a string (which is stored somewhere?) and at the end of the method, since nothing else changed, that string is returned.

Is it possible to access that value? (a little like `_` in the console, that returns the result from the last command)

Comment: You may use `end.tap { |v| puts v.inspect }`. [`Object#tap`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-tap). It yields the value to the block and returns it.

Comment: What do you mean with "console"? Are you referring to irb? Or would you like to have a breakpoint somewhere with byebug/pry and check out the previous value? Reason for asking is because all of these tools come with their own inspection tools/commands.

Comment: I don’t understand the question but perhaps you are looking for `x = if something..end` or `x = method`.

Comment: byebug it's not an option for you? if not you can take a look to Binding class

Comment: "The way ruby works gives the impression that every expression returns a value **and** it is saved somewhere." This is not really true in any practical sense. Ruby compiles your code into bytecode, which operates on an internal stack. The returned value exists only on the stack and there's no way to access it unless you e.g. assign it to a variable.

Comment: A small point regarding ",,,if no return is found...". `return` returns the last expression evaluated, so you don't need the proviso. For example, `return 7` causes the method to return `7`; `return` on a line by else (which would be unusual) returns the name of the method (a symbol).

Comment: @JordanRunning you can say "saved" is just pushed into the stack, so this is what I meant. You say there's no way of accessing it (I understand you mean from with in ruby, of course), then that's the answer. Like `_` in the irb or even the global `$_`, there might have been some magic for `pop;copy;push` hence the question.

Comment: @CarySwoveland `return` by itself is just `return nil` not that unusual. For Example, this worsk: `if true; 1; else; 2;end.tap {}` this however does not: `if true; 1; else; return 2; end.tap{}`

Comment: @estani, ah, yes, `nil`, not the method name. It's not unusual for a method to return `nil` or to see `return nil`, but, as I said, it's unusual for `return` to appear on a line by itself, even though, as you point out, it's equivalent to `return nil`. My point, however, is that the method returns the result of the last value computed, regardless of whether it is on a line that includes `return`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[based on [Aleksei Matiushkin's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58937856/is-it-possible-to-get-the-value-that-will-be-returned-from-a-function-if-its-no/58938334#comment104134352_58937856)]*

---

In Ruby, control expressions have a return value.

Your method merely returns the result of the [`if` expression](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-if+Expression). And you can inspect it via [`tap`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Object.html#method-i-tap):

```rb
def foo(b)
  if b
    123
  else
    456
  end.tap { |result| p result: result }
end

foo(true)
# prints {:result=>123}
#=> 123

foo(false)
# prints {:result=>456}
#=> 456
```

---

If you have more complicated situation without a single last expression, e.g.:

```rb
class C
  def foo(b)
    return 123 if b
    456
  end
end
```

You could use refinements to replace the method:

```rb
module M
  refine C do
    def foo(*)
      super.tap { |result| p result: result }
    end
  end
end
```

Usage:

```rb
using M

c = C.new

c.foo(true)
# prints {:result=>123}
#=> 123

c.foo(false)
# prints {:result=>456}
#=> 456
```

---

Yet another approach is to use [`TracePoint`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/TracePoint.html) to hook into the execution:

```
def foo(b)             # 1
  return 123 if b      # 2
  456                  # 3
end                    # 4

TracePoint.trace(:return) do |tp|
  puts "method `#{tp.method_id}' returned #{tp.return_value.inspect} on line ##{tp.lineno}"
end

foo(true)
foo(false)
```

Output:

```
method `foo' returned 123 on line #2
method `foo' returned 456 on line #4
```

Note that this prints the return value of all method calls. You might want to limit it to `tp.method_id == :foo`

Comment: thanks! please fix the colon, so it's complete. I guess it means you cannot access the stored value, but only tap into the last method (that's why if there's a returned involved it doesn't work, right?)

Comment: @estani there's no special variable in Ruby holding the result of the last expression evaluated. But you can nonetheless add `tap` to the method's last expression and print its result. Or replace the method temporarily with one that prints it's return value (see 2nd example)

Comment: @estani Ruby allows you to hook into the script execution via `TracePoint` (see 3rd example)

Comment: So ruby does hold all those values! `tp.return_value` is exactly what I've been looking for! Thanks!